# Strange Automapper definition when mapping IDictionary to IDictionary

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

guys.

I have a strange definition of Automapper when I try to map one `IDictionary<int, int>` to `IDictionary<int, int>` or `IDictionary<int, int>` to `IDictionary<string, int>`.

So, let's have 2 classes:

```
public class OrderProfile 
{
    public IDictionary<int, int> CountableAuxElements { get; set; } 
}

public class OrderProfileResponse 
{
    public IDictionary<int, int> CountableAuxElements { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string, int> CountableAuxElementsString { get; set; } 
}
```

So, when I create a new map through

```
CreateMap<OrderProfile, OrderProfileResponse>().ForMember(e => e.CountableAuxElementsString, f => f.Ignore()),
```

I get an error like this:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair'2[System.Int32,System.Int32]]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.Int32,System.Int32]'.
```

I tried to write code like this:

```
CreateMap<OrderProfile, OrderProfileResponse>().ForMember(e => e.CountableAuxElements, f => f.MapFrom(s => s.CountableAuxElements.ToDictionary(f => f.Key, f => f.Value)))
```

or this:

```
CreateMap<OrderProfile, OrderProfileResponse>().ForMember(e => e.CountableAuxElements, opt => opt.ConvertUsing(new DictionaryConversation<int, int, int, int>((p, context) => p, (p, context) => p), src => src.CountableAuxElements))
```

where:

```
internal class DictionaryConversation<TOldKey, TOldValue, TNewKey, TNewValue> : IValueConverter<IDictionary<TOldKey, TOldValue>, IDictionary<TNewKey, TNewValue>>
{
    private readonly Func<TOldKey, ResolutionContext, TNewKey> keyModifier;
    private readonly Func<TOldValue, ResolutionContext, TNewValue> valueModifier;

    public DictionaryConversation(Func<TOldKey, ResolutionContext, TNewKey> keyModifier, Func<TOldValue, ResolutionContext, TNewValue> valueModifier)
    {
        this.keyModifier = keyModifier;
        this.valueModifier = valueModifier;
    }

    public virtual IDictionary<TNewKey, TNewValue> Convert(IDictionary<TOldKey, TOldValue> sourceMember, ResolutionContext context) =>
               sourceMember.ToDictionary(e => keyModifier(e.Key, context), e => valueModifier(e.Value, context));
}
```

but with the same error.
The same error I have for CountableAuxElementsString when mapping it through the `ToDictionary` or `DictionaryConversation`.

What's the reason for this error? I've really had my head broken...

Thank you.

Comment: Check https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Lists-and-arrays.html. It applies to dictionaries too.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu So, If I'm not mistaken, Automapper can't work with IDictionary<,> realizing types, correct?

Comment: I took your code, pasted it one-to-one and can't reproduce the error you are having. Remember about posting a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also why bother to use `Ignore()` for `CountableAuxElementsString` if you don't have a member with such name in your source object?

Comment: Sorry, guys, I've found my mistake. It was in the configuration code like this:                 ```cfg.CreateMap(typeof(ICollection<>), typeof(ICollection<>)).IncludeAllDerived().ConvertUsing(typeof(CollectionTypeConverter<,>));``` and this part of code corrupted me. Sorry, my fault...